# Problem with updating Package Contents in Shipment using API

Tags: web-services, acumatica

I am attempting to update the Shipment / Packages tab.  The Packages area itself is updating well, but I get an error message when trying to insert into the Package Contents for each of the packages.  I believe that the issue is related to needing the ShipmentSplitLineNo as it is a key field that shows on the grid.

This is happening in Acumatica 2019 R2.
Has someone run into this issue and come up with a solution?

I have a custom endpoint, which was extended from the default (18.200.001) and added a section called PackageDetails.

[image]

Here is the error message that I get where I do the Post:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Unexpected Element: ShipmentPackageDetails
   at PX.Api.ContractBased.Soap.EntityReaderBase.ReadEntityField() in E:\Bld6\AC-FULL2019R215-JOB1\Sources\NetTools\PX.Api.ContractBased\Soap\EntityReaderBase.cs:line 288
   at PX.Api.ContractBased.Soap.EntityReaderBase.ReadEntity(String expectedEntityType) in E:\Bld6\AC-FULL2019R215-JOB1\Sources\NetTools\PX.Api.ContractBased\Soap\EntityReaderBase.cs:line 161
   at PX.Api.ContractBased.Soap.EntityReaderBase.ReadEntity(XmlReader reader, String localname, String expectedNamespace, String expectedEntityType) in E:\Bld6\AC-FULL2019R215-JOB1\Sources\NetTools\PX.Api.ContractBased\Soap\EntityReaderBase.cs:line 53
   at PX.Api.ContractBased.Soap.EntityReaderBase.ReadEntityField() in E:\Bld6\AC-FULL2019R215-JOB1\Sources\NetTools\PX.Api.ContractBased\Soap\EntityReaderBase.cs:line 269
   at PX.Api.ContractBased.Soap.EntityReaderBase.ReadEntity(String expectedEntityType) in E:\Bld6\AC-FULL2019R215-JOB1\Sources\NetTools\PX.Api.ContractBased\Soap\EntityReaderBase.cs:line 161
   at PX.Api.ContractBased.Soap.EntityReaderBase.ReadEntity(XmlReader reader, String localname, String expectedNamespace, String expectedEntityType) in E:\Bld6\AC-FULL2019R215-JOB1\Sources\NetTools\PX.Api.ContractBased\Soap\EntityReaderBase.cs:line 53
   at PX.Api.ContractBased.Soap.SoapMessageTransformerBase.BindParameters(XmlReader requestReader, MethodInfo methodInfo, Tuple`2[] parameterInfos) in E:\Bld6\AC-FULL2019R215-JOB1\Sources\NetTools\PX.Api.ContractBased\Soap\SoapMessageTransformerBase.cs:line 104
   at PX.Api.ContractBased.Soap.WebApiSoapController.Post(ISoapSystemContract systemContract, XmlReader requestReader, String serviceNamespace, String internalNamespace, MethodInfo method, Func`1 serviceFactory, IEdmModel edmModel) in E:\Bld6\AC-FULL2019R215-JOB1\Sources\NetTools\PX.Api.ContractBased\Soap\WebApiSoapController.cs:line 154
   at PX.Api.ContractBased.Soap.WebApiSoapController.<Post>d__8.MoveNext() in E:\Bld6\AC-FULL2019R215-JOB1\Sources\NetTools\PX.Api.ContractBased\Soap\WebApiSoapController.cs:line 140
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at PX.Api.ContractBased.Soap.WebApiSoapController.<Login>d__6.MoveNext() in E:\Bld6\AC-FULL2019R215-JOB1\Sources\NetTools\PX.Api.ContractBased\Soap\WebApiSoapController.cs:line 89
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.<CastToObject>d__3`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
```

Comment: I'm writing a blog post which demonstrates the solution.  The steps are too lengthy to explain here.

Comment: Could you please also share the put request body?

Comment: @ChrisH Is this the blog post?
https://www.acumatica.com/blog/rest-api-in-shipment-development/

Comment: @Kulvir yes.  But the rules don't allow to post blogs as answers